# Combining two SQL statements

Tags: sql

What would be the best way to combine the two SQL statements into one?

```
  SELECT MIN(capacity) AS mincapacity, MAX(capacity) AS maxcapacity 
  FROM room

  SELECT MIN(grade) AS mingrade, MAX(grade) AS maxgrade 
  FROM room_grade
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which returned resultset schema are you expect?

Comment: is there a common key between the two tables?

Comment: Why do you want to combine those those statements into one? At first glance it looks like a bad idea...

Comment: I need to extract the mincapacity, maxcapacity, mingrade and maxgrade values from the table.

Comment: You haven't actually given the schema for the tables nor what you want to achive but joining these seems illogical as your just getting the min and max of two columns.

Comment: @Hansi What approach would you recommend?

Comment: @hansi - As the results are independant, you don't need the schema.  I'd infer that the OP would simply prefer one query with one record to get the results, rather than 2 queries, or multiple records.  It's not that illogical to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (SELECT MIN(capacity) AS mincapacity, MAX(capacity) AS maxcapacity FROM room) AS room
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT MIN(grade) AS mingrade, MAX(grade) AS maxgrade FROM room_grade) AS room_grade
```

The main benefits here are having all the records on one row, and not joining the component records of each table.

Answer that involve a join before the aggregation will introduce a significant overhead that will make a massive difference to performance.

Comment: Wow, I thought that CROSS JOIN is a perfromance killer for such tasks, where is a trick, in aggregation function?

Comment: @sll - Aggregate, then join. So you are joining 1 record to 1 record. Rather than joining n records to m records, then aggregating.

Comment: @MatBailie
Can you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39471531/combining-update-select-sql-statements

Answer (score 4):

Given that both resultsets contain only one row each, the simplest way would be a cross join:

```
select * from
(SELECT MIN(capacity) AS mincapacity, MAX(capacity) AS maxcapacity FROM room) r
cross join
(SELECT MIN(grade) AS mingrade, MAX(grade) AS maxgrade FROM room_grade) g
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'CAPACITY', MIN(capacity) AS min, MAX(capacity) AS max 
FROM room
UNION
SELECT 'GRADE', MIN(grade) AS min, MAX(grade) AS max 
FROM room_grade
```

should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

you could do this with horrible `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT MIN(capacity) AS mincapacity, MAX(capacity) AS maxcapacity, MIN(grade) AS mingrade, MAX(grade) AS maxgrade
  FROM room, room_grade;
```

But you should use proper `JOIN` syntax

```
SELECT MIN(r.capacity) AS mincapacity, MAX(r.capacity) AS maxcapacity
    , MIN(rg.grade) AS mingrade, MAX(rg.grade) AS maxgrade
  FROM room r
  JOIN room_grade rg
    ON r.key = rg.key; (whatever the key is that joins the two tables)
```

Comment: I wouldn't do this. The join adds an unecessary overhead, and will perform dramatically worse than the two separate queries.  Also if records are present in one talbe but not the other this can change the results.

Answer (score 1):

EITHER

```
SELECT MIN(capacity) AS mincapacity, MAX(capacity) AS maxcapacity    FROM room
UNION ALL
SELECT MIN(grade) AS mingrade, MAX(grade) AS maxgrade    FROM room_grade
```

OR

```
SELECT MIN(r.capacity) AS mincapacity, MAX(r.capacity) AS maxcapacity, 
       MIN(rg.grade) AS mingrade, MAX(rg.grade) AS maxgrade    
FROM room r
INNER JOIN room_grade rg ON r.Id = rg.room_id
```

Comment: The union is messy but fine, but the join will introduce a massive overhead. Also if records are present in one table but not the other this can change the results.

Comment: Which JOIN overhead do you mean?

Comment: When specifying an INNER join, each record needs checking for existance in the other table. Keeping the queries separate yields (at worst) a full table scan of each table in the order that it currently exists. But with a join, at best, you'll need a merge join on the tables. This is much higher than niavely scanning each table independantly.

Comment: Are you talking about MS Sql Server?

Answer (score 1):

You would want to join on an ID field.  I assume the 'room' table has a unique key field, and the room_grade could have that same field.  Do a join on the two something like so.

```
SELECT MIN(r.capacity) AS mincapacity, MAX(r.capacity) AS maxcapacity, MIN(g.grade) AS mingrade, MAX(g.grade) AS maxgrade
FROM room r
inner join room_grade g
on room r.roomId = g.roomId
```

Comment: The join will introduce a massive overhead. Also if records are present in one table but not the other this can change the results.